# Uniform convergence $\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{xe^{-nx}}{e^x-1} $

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have the problem with the uniform convergence of:

$$\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{xe^{-nx}}{e^x-1} ~~~~ x\in (0, \infty)$$

I have checked $\ lim_{x\to0^+} = 0 $, however I have a problem with $\ x\to \infty $. After d'Hospital I got a little curious results.

Later I would like to tst the almost uniform convergnce and pointwise convergence, however, I can't move on without this limit. I have to compare the sup of the function with this limit, if it tends to zero.

(I suppose I would need a little help with almost uniform convergence)

Answer (score 1):

Pointwise convergence follows from the fact that $\sum e^{-nx} <\infty$ for each $x \in (0,\infty)$.

For $x \geq a$ with $a >0$ note that $\frac x {e^{x}-1} $ is bounded and $e^{-nx} \leq e^{-an}$. Hence uniform convergence holds on $[a, \infty)$. Hence the series converges almost uniformly. 
Uniform convergence  fails near $0$: $\frac {xe^{-nx}} {e^{x}-1}$ does not tend to $0$ uniformly as seen by taking $x=\frac  1n$.

Comment: Can't we use the limits? Additionally, I am not sure whether I see the pointwise convergence. What about almost uniform convergence, the uniform convergence in inervals?

Comment: The convergence is uniform on any interval $[a,\infty)$ with $a >0$.

Comment: Could you explain more your uniform convergence proof? I try to compare it with study definintions. I used to compare the sup and lim of the function.

Comment: Are you familiar with the M-test? If $|f_n(x)| \leq c_n$ with $\sum c_n <\infty$ then $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly. In our case $c_n=Me^{-an}$ where $M$ is a bound for $\frac x {e^{x}-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the idea. If I miss something, I'll write soon.